# Job scheduling algorithm for cluster

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, scheduling, scheduler, distributed-computing

I'm searching for algorithm suitable for problem below:

There are multiple computers(exact number is unknown). Each computer pulls job from some central queue, completes job, then pulls next one. Jobs are produced by some group of users. Some users submit lots of jobs, some a little. Jobs consume equal CPU time(not really, just approximation).

Central queue should be fair when scheduling jobs. Also, users who submitted lots of jobs should have some minimal share of resources.

I'm searching a good algorithm for this scheduling.

Considered two candidates:

1. Hadoop-like fair scheduler. The problem here is: where can I take minimal shares here when my cluster size is unknown?
2. Associate some penalty with each user. Increment penalty when user's job is scheduled. Use probability of scheduling job to user as `1 - (normalized penalty)`. This is something like stride scheduling, but I could not find any good explanation on it.

Answer (score 1):

when I implemented a very similar job runner (for a production system), I ended having each server up choose jobtypes at random.  This was my reasoning --

- a glut of jobs from one user should not impact the chance of other users having their jobs run (user-user fairness)
- a glut of one jobtype should not impact the chance of other jobtypes being run (user-job and job-job fairness)
- if there is only one jobtype from one user waiting to run, all servers should be running those jobs (no wasted capacity)
- the system should run the jobs "fairly", i.e. proportionate to the number of waiting users and jobtypes and not the total waiting jobs (a large volume of one jobtype should not cause scheduling to favor it) (jobtype fairness)
- the number of servers can vary, and is not known beforehand
- the waiting jobs, jobtypes and users metadata is known to the scheduler, but not the job data (ie, the usernames, jobnames and counts, but not the payloads)
- I also wanted each server to be standalone, to schedule its own work autonomously without having to know about the other servers

The solution I settled on was to track the waiting jobs by their {user,jobtype} attribute tuple, and have each scheduling step randomly select 5 tuples and from each tuple up to 10 jobs to run next.  The selected jobs were shortlisted to be run by the next available runner.  Whenever capacity freed up to run more jobs (either because jobs finished or because of secondary restrictions they could not run), ran another scheduling step to fetch more work.

Jobs were locked atomically as part of being fetched; the locks prevented them from being fetched again or participating in further scheduling decisions.  If they failed to run they were unlocked, effectively returning them to the pool.  The locks timed out, so the server running them was responsible for keeping the locks refreshed (if a server crashed, the others would time out its locks and would pick up and run the jobs it started but didn't complete)

For my use case I wanted users A and B with jobs A.1, A.2, A.3 and B.1 to each get 25% of the resources (even though that means user A was getting 75% to user B's 25%).  Choosing randomly between the four tuples probabilistically converges to that 25%.

If you want users A and B to each have a 50-50 split of resources, and have A's A.1, A.2 and A.3 get an equal share to B's B.1, you can run a two-level scheduler, and randomly choose users and from those users choose jobs.  That will distribute the resources among users equally, and within each user's jobs equally among the jobtypes.

A huge number of jobs of a particular jobtype will take a long time to all complete, but that's always going to be the case.  By picking from across users then jobtypes the responsiveness of the job processing will not be adversely impacted.

There are lots of secondary restrictions that can be added (e.g., no more than 5 calls per second to linkedin), but the above is the heart of the system.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Torque resource management and Maui batch job scheduling software from [Adaptive Computing](http://www.adaptivecomputing.com/products/open-source). Maui policies are flexible enough to fit your needs. It supports backfill, configurable job and user priorities and resource reservations.